# TableCellListener jTable creating an Action to reorder a row

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jtable

Right now I have a `JTable` called `jTable1` that has been created using the netbeans GUI feature.

Therefore I have created a `jTable` in the code it has done it for me.  So although I can call functions involving it such as `.getValue()` I am not changing things in the table using the code but rather the GUI part if that makes sense.

Anyways, I have a `jTable` with 26 rows and 2 Columns (not really important info, just thought it might be helpful).  I have also found this class called `TableCellListener` that seems very useful but Im not entirely sure how to use it, which i why I am asking.

What I want to do is monitor anytime a cell is changed and then, depending upon the new input change whatever cell previously had that value to have the value that was in the cell that was just changed.

That is I will have a row with all lowercase letter (a-z hence the 26 rows) and when say the spot with 'a' is changed to say 'z' I want the spot with 'z' to automatically update to 'a' if that makes sense.

I've read through the `TableCellListener` class and I understand that it takes a `JTable` (which I have) and an Action which I do not have nor do I know how to create it.

So I guess what I need to do is create an Acton that would "update()" the `JTable` in the way I described above since the TableCellListener takes an Action (which I am unfamiliar with).

If anyone could help me on this I would be much apprecaited.

One other thing I have been looking to do as well is to limit my one row to only take in 1 character (i.e. 'a'-'z').  I have read about the custom editors but I'm unsure of how to implement one to just take a single character.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) section of the [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#) tutorial?

Comment: You should also have a look at [TableRowSorter#setSortsOnUpdates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#setSortsOnUpdates(boolean))

Comment: That wouldnt really help with what I am trying to do, because I don't need it to sort in a SPECIFIC way but rather any random way that the user decides to change the letters

Comment: So? Write a TableRowSorter to do it, the API is very flexible

Comment: Okay, now I can read your question, you need to customise the `TableModel` and override it's `setValueAt` and use it to customise the way the model is update. I'd also do some research into `` to control what you can type into a field

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Make a class which extends from something `AbstractTableModel` or `DefaultTableModel` depending on your needs, override it's `setValueAt` method and implement your logic